# Pass Array containing either class or struct

Tags: arrays, function, class, swift, struct

In Swift I declared a function that differs from `Array.count` only in that if `array == nil` the function returns `0`. This is related to my `UITableViewDataSource`, but that's not important here. The problem is, if I declare the function as:

```
class func countOfItemsInArray(array: [AnyObject]?) -> Int
```

and then try to pass it an array of structs, it declares that the structs in the array do not conform to `AnyObject`. I understand why that is (I think), but is there a way to make this work with classes **and** structs, or should I just give in to copy and paste?

Answer (score 3):

Generics are probably better suited to this problem than relying on covariance of `[AnyObject]`.  A version of `countElements` that worked on an optional array and returned 0 in case of `nil` could go like this:

```
func countElements<T>(array: [T]?) -> Int {
    return array?.count ?? 0
}
```

When you call `countElements` with any kind of array, the placeholder `T` is replaced with the type of the element contained in the array.

Note, this version overloads the existing `countElements` with a version that takes an optional.  If you call it with a non-optional or any other kind of collection, the Swift version would be called, if you pass in an optional array, this one will be called.  It’s debatable whether this is a good practice (I think it’s fine) or a bad one (some may disapprove :).

A version that works on any collection type would be:

```
func countElements<C: CollectionType>(col: C?) -> C.Index.Distance {
    return col.map { countElements($0) } ?? 0
}
```

Comment: Your solution with generics is perfect. However I am among those who would avoid overriding a Swift standard function. More specifically I admit I don't know if Cocoa (and other OS libraries/frameworks) can see your version of countElements. If the can maybe the override approach is a little insecure.

Comment: There’s no risk from Cocoa (even if it was a possibility which I suspect it is not) calling this version, since the the Swift version comes ahead of it in the overload resolution priority (even though Swift will implicitly upconvert non-optionals to optionals,  calls that require that appear to come lower in the pecking order).  I would _not_ advocate overloading an existing function in a way that would cause ambiguity for existing callers (though I guess you could do it unwittingly).

Comment: Ok in your declaration you did not use the "public" access control modifier. So your version of **countElements** is visibile only inside the project where it is declared. Then it should not interfere with other library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` you can pass any type, so also structs:

```
class func countOfItemsInArray(array: [Any]?) -> Int
```

---

This is kind of weird.

I used this function:

```
func countOfItemsInArray(array: [Any]?) -> Int {
    return array != nil ? array!.count : 0
}
```

Declared two of your `Assignment` structs and put them in an array:

```
let structOne = Assignment(name: "1", dueDate: NSDate(), subject: "1")
let structTwo = Assignment(name: "2", dueDate: NSDate(), subject: "2")
let myArray: [Assignment] = [structOne, structTwo]
```

But here's the interesting part.
When calling `println(countOfItemsInArray(myArray))` it gives the error:

```
<stdin>:27:33: error: 'Assignment' is not identical to 'Any'
println(countOfItemsInArray(myArray))
^
<stdin>:17:26: note: in initialization of parameter 'array'
func countOfItemsInArray(array: [Any]?) -> Int {
^
```

So I tested if `myArray` is of type `[Any]`:

```
println(myArray is [Any])
```

to which swift says:

```
<stdin>:25:17: error: 'Any' is not a subtype of 'Assignment'
println(myArray is [Any])
^
```

But when I change the type annotation of `myArray` to `[Any]` it works:

```
let myArray: [Any] = [structOne, structTwo]
```

And when simply handing the literal to the function it works, too:

```
countOfItemsInArray([structOne, structTwo])
```

The whole code example can be seen [here](http://swiftstub.com/598961090/).

Comment: I'm getting an error, "'myStructType'  is not identical to 'Any'"